# DNS resolution fails with "SERVFAIL" after running "udevadm trigger"

Tags: networking, dns, udev

I'm experiencing an issue where DNS resolution fails with a "SERVFAIL" error after executing the "udevadm trigger" command on my Ubuntu Server. I've noticed that this problem occurs consistently whenever I run that command:

```bash
root@backend:~# nslookup azure.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   azure.com
Address: 20.43.132.131
Name:   azure.com
Address: 191.235.228.36
...

root@backend:~# udevadm trigger
root@backend:~# nslookup azure.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can`t find azure.com: SERVFAIL

root@backend:~# systemctl restart NetworkManager
root@backend:~# nslookup azure.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   azure.com
Address: 20.50.2.51
Name:   azure.com
Address: 20.37.196.198
...
```

Could anyone provide insights into why running "udevadm trigger" might cause DNS resolution to fail?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (5.15.0-46-generic)